# How to make this Java summation stream more compact?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this stream from a Map that sums the integers from a method call on an object based on a certain condition.

I would like to know how to make it more compact and efficient.

```
int total = myMap.values().stream()
    .filter(obj -> obj.countsInt())
    .mapToInt(MyObject::getInt)
    .sum();
```

Comment: Other than replacing the lambda with a method reference `MyObject::countsInt`, I don't think there is anything else you can do; this code is already compact.

Comment: "and effiicient" in what regard? speed? how big is the map?

Comment: I was looking for something on the lines of what Yassin Hajaj suggested. I felt there could be a better way to do the summation without using mapToInt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a method reference for `obj.countsInt()` and also use `Collectors.summingInt()` for your reducing method

```
int total = myMap.values()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(MyObject::countsInt)
                 .collect(summingInt(MyObject::getInt));
```

Answer (score 1):

Compactness:

Use method references:

```
obj -> obj.countsInt()
```

can be replace by

```
MyObject::countsInt
```

Ignoring that, you could go straight to ints replacing:

```
.filter(obj -> obj.countsInt()).mapToInt(MyObject::getInt)
```

with

```
.mapToInt(obj -> obj.countsInt() ? 0 : obj.getInt())
```

But if you want efficiency, don't use streams.